# Does scroll works with ie11 in sencha touch?

Tags: scroll, sencha-touch, internet-explorer-11

I have dataview with large number of rows. I want to scroll it vertically. The scroll behavior is fine in chrome and iPad but IE 11 does not scroll. When i scroll, it goes up after scrolling. It does not stop at the scrolling position.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add scrollable configuration to your navigation view and its children:

```
scrollable: {
    direction: 'vertical'
}
```